# Django Admin: two ListFilter Spanning multi-valued relationships

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have a Blog model and an Entry model, following the example in [django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships).

Entry has a ForeignKey to Blog: one Blog has several Entries.

I have two FieldListFilters for Blog: one for "Entry title", one for "Entry published year".

If in the Blog list admin page I filter for both `entry__title='Lennon'` and `entry__published_year=2008`, then I see all Blogs which have at least one entry with title "Lennon" and at least one entry from 2008. *They do not have to be the same entry.*

However, that's not what I want. What I want is to filter blogs which have entries that have both got the title "Lennon" *and* are from 2008.

So for example say I have this data:

| Blog | Entry Title | Entry year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | McCartney | 2008 |
| A | Lennon | 2009 |
| B | Lennon | 2008 |

The admin list page for Blog currently filters in Blog A, because it has one entry from 2008 and one entry for "Lennon", as well as Blog B. I only want to see Blog B.

This is because django does this when it builds the queryset:

```
qs = qs.filter(title_filter)
qs = qs.filter(published_filter)
```

As per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships), to get the desired result it would need to make just one filter call:

```
qs = qs.filter(title_filter & published_filter)
```

How can I achieve this behaviour with filtering in the admin?

## Background:

Both filters are different concerning filtering on many-to-many relationships. See above link to the docs.

```
MyModel.filter(a=b).filter(c=d)
```

```
MyModel.filter(a=b, c=d)
```

Comment: Can you show your existing admin models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the fundamental problem as you point out is that django builds the queryset by doing a sequence of filters, and once a filter is "in" the queryset, it's not easy to alter it, because each filter builds up the queryset's `Query` object.

However, it's not impossible. This solution is generic and requires no knowledge of the models / fields you're acting on, but probably only works for SQL backends, uses non-public APIs (although in my experience these internal APIs in django are pretty stable), and it could get funky if you are using other custom `FieldListFilter`. The name was the best I could come up with:

```py
from django.contrib.admin import (
    FieldListFilter,
    AllValuesFieldListFilter,
    DateFieldListFilter,
)

def first(iter_):
    for item in iter_:
        return item
    return None


class RelatedANDFieldListFilter(FieldListFilter):
    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        # clone queryset to avoid mutating the one passed in
        queryset = queryset.all()

        qs = super().queryset(request, queryset)

        if len(qs.query.where.children) == 0:
            # no filters on this queryset yet, so just do the normal thing
            return qs

        new_lookup = qs.query.where.children[-1]
        new_lookup_table = first(
            table_name
            for table_name, aliases in queryset.query.table_map.items()
            if new_lookup.lhs.alias in aliases
        )
        if new_lookup_table is None:
            # this is the first filter on this table, so nothing to do.
            return qs

        # find the table being joined to for this filter
        main_table_lookup = first(
            lookup
            for lookup in queryset.query.where.children
            if lookup.lhs.alias == new_lookup_table
        )
        assert main_table_lookup is not None

        # Rebuild the lookup using the first joined table, instead of the new join to the same
        # table but with a different alias in the query.
        #
        # This results in queries like:
        #
        #   select * from table
        #   inner join other_table on (
        #       other_table.field1 == 'a' AND other_table.field2 == 'b'
        #   )
        #
        # instead of queries like:
        #
        #   select * from table
        #   inner join other_table other_table on other_table.field1 == 'a'
        #   inner join other_table T1 on T1.field2 == 'b'
        #
        # which is why this works.
        new_lookup_on_main_table_lhs = new_lookup.lhs.relabeled_clone(
            {new_lookup.lhs.alias: new_lookup_table}
        )
        new_lookup_on_main_table = type(new_lookup)(new_lookup_on_main_table_lhs, new_lookup.rhs)

        queryset.query.where.add(new_lookup_on_main_table, 'AND')
        return queryset
```

Now you can just make `FieldListFilter` subclasses and mix it in, I've just done the ones you wanted from the example:

```py
class RelatedANDAllValuesFieldListFilter(RelatedANDFieldListFilter, AllValuesFieldListFilter):
    pass


class RelatedANDDateFieldListFilter(RelatedANDFieldListFilter, DateFieldListFilter):
    pass


@admin.register(Blog)
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (
        ("entry__pub_date", RelatedANDDateFieldListFilter),
        ("entry__title", RelatedANDAllValuesFieldListFilter),
    )
```

Comment: @dapthdazz wow, that's a great solution. And thank yo for updating the answer and adding a table of example data.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.filters import AllValuesFieldListFilter, DateFieldListFilter

from .models import Blog, Entry


class EntryTitleFilter(AllValuesFieldListFilter):
    def expected_parameters(self):
        return []


class EntryPublishedFilter(DateFieldListFilter):
    def expected_parameters(self):
        # Combine all of the actual queries into a single 'filter' call
        return [
            "entry__pub_date__gte",
            "entry__pub_date__lt",
            "entry__pub_date__isnull",
            "entry__title",
            "entry__title__isnull",
        ]

@admin.register(Blog)
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (
        ("entry__pub_date", EntryPublishedFilter),
        ("entry__title", EntryTitleFilter),
    )
```

#### How this works

1. Under the hood, when a filter is initiated, django loops through the query parameters (from the request), and if they are in that filters' 'expected parameters', it stores them in a dict called `self.used_parameters`.
2. All built-in list filters apart from `EmptyFieldListFilter` inherit their `queryset` method from `FieldListFilter`. This method simply does `queryset.filter(**self.used_parameters)`.
3. So by over-riding the `expected_parameters` method, we can control what happens when each filter is applied. In this case, we do all of the actual filtering in the entry-published filter.

Answer (score 1):

Django apply **list_filter sequentially** in the list and checks every time **queryset()** method of list filter class. If return **queryset is not None** then django assign queryset = modified_queryset_by_the_filter.

we can use these points.

we can make two custom class filter for this,

first **EntryTitleFilter**  class which queryset() method return **None**.

second **MyDateTimeFilter** class in which we access query params of both filter class then apply according to our requirement.

```
from django.contrib.admin.filters import DateFieldListFilter

class EntryTitleFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Entry Title'
    parameter_name = 'title'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return [(item.title, item.title) for item in Entry.objects.all()]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        # it returns None so queryset is not modified at this time.
        return None


class MyDateFilter(DateFieldListFilter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDateFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        # access title query params
        title = request.GET.get('title')

        if len(self.used_parameters) and title:
            # if we have query params for both filter then
            start_date = self.used_parameters.get('entry__pub_date__gte')
            end_end = self.used_parameters.get('entry__pub_date__lt')
            blog_ids = Entry.objects.filter(
                        pub_date__gte=start_date,
                        pub_date__lt=end_end,
                        title__icontains=title
                    ).values('blog')
            queryset = queryset.filter(id__in=blog_ids)
        elif len(self.used_parameters):
            # if only apply date filter
            queryset = queryset.filter(**self.used_parameters)
        elif title:
            # if only apply title filter
            blog_ids = Entry.objects.filter(title__icontains=title).values('blog')
            queryset = queryset.filter(id__in=blog_ids)
        else:
            # otherwise
            pass
        return queryset



@admin.register(Blog)
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = [EntryTitleFilter, ('entry__pub_date', MyDateFilter),]
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Let filters spanning multi-valued relationships be handled in `ChangeList.get_queryset`'s `qs.filter(**remaining_lookup_params)` by returning an empty list `[]` in `expected_parameters`.

Unlike a few of the other answers, this avoids the dependency between filters.

Filter implementations and usage:

```py
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Blog, Entry


class EntryTitleFieldListFilter(admin.AllValuesFieldListFilter):
    def expected_parameters(self):
        return []  # Let filters spanning multi-valued relationships be handled in ChangeList.get_queryset: qs.filter(**remaining_lookup_params)


class EntryPublishedFieldListFilter(admin.AllValuesFieldListFilter):
    def __init__(self, field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path):
        super().__init__(field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path)
        field_path = 'entry__pub_date__year'
        self.lookup_kwarg = field_path
        self.lookup_kwarg_isnull = '%s__isnull' % field_path
        self.lookup_val = params.get(self.lookup_kwarg)
        self.lookup_val_isnull = params.get(self.lookup_kwarg_isnull)
        queryset = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
        self.lookup_choices = queryset.distinct().order_by(self.lookup_kwarg).values_list(self.lookup_kwarg, flat=True)

    def expected_parameters(self):
        return []  # Let filters spanning multi-valued relationships be handled in ChangeList.get_queryset: qs.filter(**remaining_lookup_params)


@admin.register(Blog)
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (
        ('entry__title', EntryTitleFieldListFilter),
        ('entry__pub_date', EntryPublishedFieldListFilter),
    )
```

---

Code reference for `ChangeList.get_queryset`'s `qs.filter(**remaining_lookup_params)`:

> ```py
> def get_queryset(self, request):
>     # First, we collect all the declared list filters.
>     (
>         self.filter_specs,
>         self.has_filters,
>         remaining_lookup_params,
>         filters_use_distinct,
>         self.has_active_filters,
>     ) = self.get_filters(request)
>     # Then, we let every list filter modify the queryset to its liking.
>     qs = self.root_queryset
>     for filter_spec in self.filter_specs:
>         new_qs = filter_spec.queryset(request, qs)
>         if new_qs is not None:
>             qs = new_qs
>
>     try:
>         # Finally, we apply the remaining lookup parameters from the query
>         # string (i.e. those that haven't already been processed by the
>         # filters).
>         qs = qs.filter(**remaining_lookup_params)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

how about this when overriding the queryset method:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    title_filter = Q(entry_title='Lennon')
    published_filter = Q(entry_published_year=2008)
            
    return queryset.filter(title_filter | published_filter )
```

You any use any operators like &(bitwise AND), |(bitwise OR) like this.

Comment: Yes, this would work. Instead of creating two ListFilter, I create one ListFilter and there can execute both filter in one `filter()` call.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
entries = Entry.objects.filter(title='Lennon', published_year=2008)
blogs = Blog.objects.filter(entry__in=entries)
```

Comment: Yes, this work if you can use the ORM. I am using the django-admin and two ListFilter. The ListFilter can only implement a `queryset()` method. Sorry, your answer is great, but does not fit to the question.